# extension on typo3 page

Tags: typo3

I have created a page in typo3. Created and install extension through Extension kickstarter. Add this newly created extension on my page. But the extension is not showing up. Do anyone has any idea? Is template file needs to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line on the setup template of the page and it resolves my problem

page.40 < plugin.tx_test3_pi1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have included the Typoscript of the extension as well.

Usually it's done via 'Include static', the installed extension should be within the available items.

[image]